# How can I force xAxis to be "number" type like a double?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

There is no option except for DateTime Intervals

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = ???

There does no seem to me an AxisType under xAxis.

I am trying to create a Scatter plot using a Points ChartType and my xAxis remains stubbornly ad DateTime

```
        chart1.Series.Add(seriesName);
        chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
        chart1.Series[seriesName].Color = Color.Red;
        chart1.Series[seriesName].BorderWidth = 1;
        chart1.Series[seriesName].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        chart1.Series[seriesName].MarkerSize = 5;
        chart1.Series[seriesName].ChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
        chart1.Series[seriesName].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;

double[] xData = FillArraySomeHow();
double[] yData= FillArraySomeHow();

        for (int i = 0; i < yData.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                double x = i;
                if (xData != null)
                {
                    x = xData[i];
                }
                chart.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(x, yData[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Is this for MSChart? Some other chart? A bit more detail is required please.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Seems to be using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.intervaltype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do you add your data? Show us the code and make it clear what type the x-values are!! Of course if you look closer you can see `DateTimeIntervalType.Number` but the real issue is not the Interval but: `chart1.Series[0].XValueType`..

Comment: I add part of the code and an edit

Comment: Hm, that looks fine to me.. Can you add an image that shows the problem? Do you set the format of the axis labels? As it is it works fine here. (excpt for the typo `chart` <-> `chart1`)